# Which is grammatically correct: "Trader Town" or "Traders Town" (or both)?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

Let me put this in context for you: I'm developing a project which will be called Trader Town or Traders Town. As you might have noticed it's a space dedicated for traders; analysis, statistics, etc.

But I don't know which one sounds right in English. Riders Town or Rider Town.

Maybe both sound good?

Actually now I'm thinking this is pretty much a opinion-based question.

Let me be clear, I'm not asking for an opinion, I just want to know whether Traders Town or Trader Town are grammatically correct.

Comment: Whatever sounds good to you and conveys the meaning you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When we want to *name* a company, or a fictitious town,  there are no fixed rules. No one can tell you that *Traders Town* is preferable to *Trader Town* or vice versa, there are only opinions.

For instance, *Traders Town* could be mistaken as the surname of someone called Traders. In a formal English document, the possessive apostrophe would probably be required to denote that a group of traders own a town, i.e. *The **traders’ town***, but more often than not, [toponyms](https://www.thoughtco.com/toponym-place-name-1692554) omit the possessive apostrophe.

In English, a common way to describe a location after an activity would be to use the present participle;  **Trading Town**, a town where trading is performed. Similarly, a *[fishing village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_village)*, a place where fishing is the main occupation, a *[shipbuilding town](http://www.bbc.co.uk/wear/content/articles/2008/01/16/shipbuilding_has_been_20_years_feature.shtml)* would indicate a shipping industry, and a [*market town*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_town), a place where markets are held.

Often, historical cities and towns were named after professions or titles, e.g. *[Bakersville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakersville)*, a place where bakers lived or worked; [Smithville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smithville) a place perhaps famous for *one smith* or a number of smiths who worked with an assortment of metals. And finally, *[Princes Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princes_Street)*, in Edinburgh, named after King George's two eldest sons: Prince George, and Prince Frederick.

Comment: You know that naming is off-topic, but I'll only downvote if someone upvotes as this is a good summary.